# Presta Sitemap Bundle Install Error

Tags: php, xml, symfony, composer-php, sitemap

I have followed the presta sitemap bundle documentation and I am still having issues.

I have this line in my composer.json file:

"presta/sitemap-bundle": "dev-master"

But I get this error:

- A typo in the package name
- The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting

On a side note if anyone can recommend me a better way to do xml sitemaps with symfony2, that would be great also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to avoid installing branches! Their stability is always "dev", and you cannot be sure which version you are installing or updating to.

"presta/sitemap-bundle" has several tagged releases [according to Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/presta/sitemap-bundle), currently ranging from 1.0.0 to 1.4.0. Pick one of these versions (there is nothing wrong with using the latest one unless you have to choose an older version due to compatibility with other installed packages), and allow for updates if you like:

```
composer require presta/sitemap-bundle
# installs a version close to the latest if other packages allow it, with default update possibility

composer require presta/sitemap-bundle:~1.4
# forces to at least install version 1.4, allowing for compatible feature updates like 1.5, 1.99,..., but no incompatible version 2.0

composer require presta/sitemap-bundle:1.4.*
# this only allows bugfix updates of 1.4.x versions.
```

Comment: I generated a sitemap using a different method. This information is still useful for future bundle installs. Thank you.